# Is the language $L = \{{a^{2n+1}b^{m+2}a^n | m \neq 2n}\}$ context-free?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, pumping-lemma

$L = \{{a^{2n+1}b^{m+2}a^n | m \neq 2n}\}$

I tried to split $L$ in 2: when $m > 2n$ and $m<2n$, however both resulting languages are not context-free, so I did not find out anything about $L$.

The pumping lemma did not give any results either, because the string $a^{2p+1}b^pa^p$ for example can be pumped when $vwx$ is in $b^p$.

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer?

Comment: I’ve just passed the exam, so now I’m only curios about the answer, but maybe leaving it here would help others that stumble across this question.